# Craft 4 upgrade. Entry throwing 'craft\models\EntryDraft doesn’t exist' error in admin

Tags: craft4

After upgrading to Craft 4 a few entries are throwing this error in the admin (Locally):

> craft\models\EntryDraft doesn’t exist or doesn’t extend/implement craft\base\ElementInterface

Not all do this but a few do.

Creating new entries works just fine and everything works otherwise.

I tried pruning revisions and drafts. No luck.

Deleted the rows in the drafts and revisions tables of the DB. No luck.

I have an old DB and wonder if some old entries could be grumpy for whatever reason.

I have requested an up-to-date DB I hope won't have this problem. But this will take a while to get.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@MoritzLost's answer is partly correct, but this particular error is not due to outdated code in your project.

The `EntryDraft` class was [deprecated in Craft 3.2.0](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/v3/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated-33), but for some unknown reason (possibly due to a failed or incomplete migration from that era) a lot of installs that have since upgraded, still retain entries using that class for their `type` column in the `elements` table.

After upgrading to Craft 4, attempting to load those entries will throw that exception, since the deprecated `EntryDraft` class was finally removed in 4.0 and Craft no longer knows how to deal with those entries.

**The fix is to change any instances of `craft\models\EntryDraft` in the `elements` table, to `craft\elements\Entry` – for example via an `UPDATE` query:**

```sql
UPDATE elements SET type = 'craft\\elements\\Entry' WHERE type = 'craft\\models\\EntryDraft'
```

*If you're curious how many of these "EntryDraft" entries you have in your install, you can run the following SQL query (before updating the `type` column, of course):*

```sql
SELECT id FROM elements WHERE type='craft\\models\\EntryDraft'
```

Comment: Ah, good to know! One of the reasons I'm not particularly fond of the element type being kept in the database … :s

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Mats!
This fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The class [`craft\models\EntryDraft` exists in Craft 3](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-models-entrydraft.html) but is gone in [Craft 4](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/). If you're getting this error, it means you still have some code in your project that was written for Craft 3 and needs to be updated for Craft 4. This can either be a site module or an external plugin. To find where this is coming from, check the error log, which should include a stack trace. If it doesn't, search for `EntryDraft` in the entire project (the `modules/` and `vendor/` folders are the most likely candidates) to find out where that class is referenced.

If it's coming from a site module, you need to update the code in that module to work with Craft 4. If it's a plugin, update to the latest version and/or contact the maintainers to get this bug fixed. It's unlikely to be a plugin, because Composer wouldn't allow you to install Craft 4 as long as you have plugins installed that don't have a version that is compatible with Craft 4.

Comment: Thanks, MoritzLost! That has given me some good leads to follow. 
Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather write a Craft migration than directly modify the database, you can use the following:

```
    public function safeUp(): bool
    {

        $this->update(
            '{{%elements}}', // The table name
            ['type' => 'craft\\elements\\Entry'], // Column to update
            ['type' => 'craft\\models\\EntryDraft'] // Condition to filter which rows to update
        );

        return true;
    }
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
mysql> UPDATE elements SET type = 'craft\\elements\\Entry' WHERE type = 'craft\\models\\EntryDraft'
```